# Sheet Metal Bending: stuck on calculating the minimum radius required

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, metals, moments, yield-point

I'm used to calculate the minimum radius required for bending operations on both aluminum and steel sheets, given the following parameters: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxEBc.jpg

**Problem statement:**

> For a sheet metal stock with  inch thickness, determine the minimum
>   tool radius for both the steel and aluminum alloys that will not tear
>   the material. Assume the sheet of material is in pure bending (i.e.,
>   no additional tension is applied during forming).

I have already learned about the following formulas:

- R = 1/k
- k(y) = e(y) / (h/2)
- e(y) = k.y

Given that R = 1/k, the next step is to find the maximum curvature k for each sheet.

The problem is that I don't know how to find the maximum curvature, and I'm still stuck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there an error in your equations? Does R depend on little k, or big K? What are y and h? My guess is that y is distance from neutral plane and h is total wall thickness. If I have this all correct in my head, your equations are monotonic in all the variables, so there is no maximum. Are you perhaps missing a constraining equation that relates radius to stress in the material?

Comment: @starrise There is no big K, sorry but I meant 'k' the curvature. y = distance from the neutral axis to the top of the sheet cross-section. h = thickness of the sheet.

Comment: @starrise "Are you perhaps missing a constraining equation that relates radius to stress in the material?" - There is no constraining equation specific to the problem. But I'm pretty sure that there is a solution for finding the minimalist radius.

Comment: @starrise I updated the question in order to provide more information about the problem, please check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think that there is a constraint, but based on the answer from Derkooh it is empirically derived. I suppose what I was getting at is that the tighter the radius, the greater the plastic strain. If the strain exceeds the failure strain the material ruptures. So stress/strain must be related to this in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the following helps.  This is from a book I used in college. Manufacturing Engineering and Technology, 5th Ed. by Kalpakjian and Schmid

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

## Minimum Bend Radius

`Where **r** is the tensile reduction of area.`

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing - that book seems interesting. If I understand correctly, the minimalist radius can be obtained by `Rmin = 1 / ((2/(h.k)) + 1)`?

Comment: I highlighted the min bend radius equation

Comment: Perfect. What is `r`, then?

Comment: `r` is tensile reduction of area, and is approximated through the chart in Fig. 16.18..  I also added Fig 16.16 to the derivation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm unable to determine it from the figure. Also how can I obtain it?

Comment: R/T is the y-axis, and r (tensile reduction of area) is the x-axis.

Comment: `R/T` is the y-axis, and `r` (tensile reduction of area) is the x-axis.  Minimum bend radius `R` is a function of material thickness and material, and is empirically defined from table 16.3.  Eq. 16.5 can be solved for `r` as follows:  `r = 50 / (R/T +1) `

Comment: Still available on Amazon : a good investment? https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Manufacturing+Engineering+and+Technology

Comment: @Derkooh OK. Your answer is informative, but it hasn't yet provided a solution for the problem, given the params provided at https://imgur.com/a/7akHC. Could you please provide a solution for the calculus of the Rmin of both steel and aluminum sheets?

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, for sure.

Comment: @Kais Derkooh says at the top of his answer "I hope the following helps" so it's now down to you to apply the information...

Comment: @Kais R =6T from table 16.5 if you assume the material is hard aluminum.  No calculus is needed.  Chart 16.18 is empirically defined for multiple materials.

Comment: @Derkooh Ok, understood.